# Place is not getting saved with feed post

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a a feed story to Facebook using the code below. The post gets saved with the message, however, it is does save the place. If I do this same thing from the graph explorer it works. Any idea what might be going on?

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed'
params = {
    'message': 'Hi',
    'place': 110445549019685,
    'access_token': token
}
req = urllib2.Request(url)

data, content_type = urllib3.filepost.encode_multipart_formdata(params)
req.add_header('Content-Type', content_type)
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(data))
req.add_data(data)

conn = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
response = conn.read()
```

Comment: I've got the exact same issue. Any resolution yet?